# dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../

Tags: objective-c, frameworks

A custom framework let say DownloadToExcel is provided by a third party.
I am creating a framework and needs to include the same in that. 
I did the same by adding it into Link Binaries with Libraries as well as Copy Files to Destination in Build Phases.

When I run my application it works fine.
However, whenever, I add my custom framework into a application, then while it is running with the following crash.

dyld: Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/

Reason: image not found

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Rohit

Answer (score 0):

in the target's **General** tab, there is an **Embedded Binaries** field, add **framework** there, and the crash should be resolved. I had same issue and it Resolved it!